# Alternative for Function in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have read that having a function in the WHERE clause slows things down (Not SARGABLE). I am now facing this situation with a query like this ...

In the query below, Fn is a built-in CRM Dynamics DateTime function to convert UTCTime to LocalTime

```
SELECT 
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    Column4,
    Fn(UTCTimeColumn) AS LocalTimeColumn
FROM
    SomeTable
WHERE
    Fn(UTCTimeColumn) between '2 Jan 2015 00:00:00.000' and '8 Jan 2015 23:59:59.000'
```

Also tried this ...

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        Column1,
        Column2,
        Column3,
        Column4,
        Fn(UTCTimeColumn) AS LocalTimeColumn
    FROM
    SomeTable) T    
WHERE
    T.LocalTimeColumn between '2 Jan 2015 00:00:00.000' and '8 Jan 2015 23:59:59.000'
```

Having a function like this in the WHERE clause makes things crawl.

- How can I improve the performance?
- What are my alternatives?

Comment: You really can't, because the function has to be called for every row in the data.  Why not use built-in date/time functions?

Comment: I guess, having any function in the WHERE clause will be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a persisted column which will call the function once:

```
add column LocalTimeColumn as Fn(UTCTimeColumn) persisted
```

Comment: This is awesome, can you give an example of usage?

Comment: @Zach: it's just a column now you query as usually